# How to trigger a condition transition using a cyclic event in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, events, anylogic, statechart

I wanted to change the state of the agent(s) by a cyclic event(reset) [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsoBn.jpg). What command should I used to trigger the transition(resetHome) every 24hrs after the first initial 12 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Switch it to a msg-based transition, set the expected keyword to "myTrigger" (or whatever you like).

In the event, write `DeliveryAddressStaechart.fireEvent("MyTrigger");`

This will trigger the transition if (and only if) is in the `DefaultHomeAddress`  state.

PS: You should never use condition-based transitions, not good practice